# Hyperledger Fabric with Java: problems during the deployment of the Fabcar's sample chaincode

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, gradlew, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

According to the documentation at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html, I'm trying to deploy the Fabcar Chaincode by using Java. After run the network and created a channel, I used the command **deployCC -l java** to deploy the smart contract but I received the following error:

[Output of the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl4UN.png)

Could you please help me?

Comment: I think there is some issue in compilation of the chaincode.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure that ".jar" is in the right folder (this is the main issue for this error). What do you suggest to check? Thx

Comment: Please check for `gradle-wrapper.jar ` file, if it is there in build environment.

Comment: Yes it is! I don't understand...